# Monge–Ampère operator

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, complex-geometry, harmonic-analysis

I'm studying the article of Bedford–Taylor "[Fine topology, Šilov boundary…](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-1236(87)90087-5)" but I don't
understand the proof of the following proposition.

Let $u$, $v$ be plurisubharmonic functions defined on $\Omega$, an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$, such that
$u,v\in L^{\infty}_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$.

Let $O$  be a fine-open subset of $\Omega$ where $u>v$.
Then
$(dd^{c}\max(u,v))^{n}\rvert O=(dd^{n}u)^{n}\rvert O$.

They say that if $O$ is open then it is obvious, while if $O$ is just fine open then it is shown using a decreasing approximation sequence $u_k$ of smooth functions for $u$.

Then
since $O=\bigcap_{k}(u_k>v)$ and since $(dd^{c}\max(u_k,v))^{n}\rvert O_k=(dd^{n}u_k)^{n}\rvert O_k$ (this I don't understand), where $O_k=(u_k>v)$, the statement holds.

Maybe it is trivial but I'm not able to see it.

Comment:  On $O_k$, $max\{u_k,v\}=u_k$. Or is it something else that is the problem? 

Comment: yes i see it, but even on $O$ $u=\max(u,v)$ so i don't understand why he passes to an approximation sequence.

Comment: This isn't a complete answer, but may help. For smooth u_k, u_k >v is an open set. For non-smooth u, this is not necessarily the case. It may have a boundary. Just outside the boundary max(u,v) = v and inside max(u,v) = u. So, whilst testing the current against test functions whose support "ends" at the boundary, it isn't obvious (to me) that dd^c(max(u,v)) = dd^c (u). 

Comment: Hi digital: I can not give comments, hence give answer here for your answer. If O is not open, then u=max(u,v) on O does not neccessarily imply that dd^cu=dd^cmax (u,v) on a neighborhood of O, so that when restricting to O you get the equality. (If you want to do derivatives, you need to do it on an open set).

Answer (score 0):

As a psh function, v is usc, so the set O_k is open, hence one can apply the usual locality property of Bedford--Taylor product.